# Elasticsearch ShieldPlugin ClassNotFoundException

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-shield

I'm trying to use shield plugin with elasticsearch while creating a es client in spring. I have added the following dependency to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>shield</artifactId>
<version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm creating the bean in the below fashion:

```
@Override
protected TransportClient createInstance() throws Exception
{
    TransportClient client = null;
    String userpass = this.username+":"+this.password;
    client = TransportClient.builder()
    .addPlugin(ShieldPlugin.class)
    .settings(Settings.builder()
        .put("shield.user", userpass)
        .build()).build()
    .addTransportAddress(toAddress());
    return client;
}
```

But when the bean is created it gets the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.shield.ShieldPlugin
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    ... 116 more
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the Elastic.co support to fix this point.
It was not the good dependency on the maven repository.
Now the maven repository should work fine.

BR

Nicolas

Answer (score -1):

Go to the official website to download jar, you can solve it

[enter link description here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/installing-shield.html#deb-rpm-install)